# The question ended up to be wrong. What should I do?

Tags: discussion, questions

I've asked a question on SO, which after some research the question ended up to be wrong.

In this context, wrong means "the problem had actually nothing to do with the original question, and simply rephrasing the question changes everything"

I'm thinking about deleting the question, but it can help someone that is willing to read the comments

I'm thinking about rephrasing it, but then all the answers/comments end up being irrelevant

[This is the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23963481/how-can-i-send-emails-using-my-own-mail-server-in-meteor) that caused me to think about this issue

Comment: Honestly? I'd delete it, I personally hate running into such questions when searching for a problem and running into a completely different problem with an irrelevant answer. Happens to the best of us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the question has no answers you can delete your question.

**In your case when** it has answers you can flag the question "**need moderator attention**",
and explaining you want to delete it.

Keep in mind if the question got answers with positive score the question might not be deleted.

Comment: I believe you can't delete a question if it has (any answer with >= 1 score) or (2 or more answers). I could be wrong though.

Comment: @gunr2171 Yeah but moderators can delete questions with positive score answers .

Comment: That seemed standard enough, therefore that's what I did